# Backgroundworker ProgressChanged acts after the worker is done

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, multithreading

I've created a form to pop up and display a progress bar whenever I call one of my time-consuming routines. I feed the progress of my routine through the `UpdateProgress` method.

I'm using a background worker to allow the user to move the form around and keep doing their business while this form updates. However, the form just locks up until the routine is complete, then quickly ramps the progress bar to 100% and quits (as it should). The progress bar should, imo, update alongside the progress of the calls being made to the `UpdateProgress` method.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class ProgressIndicator : Form
    {
        int progressPercentage;

        public ProgressIndicator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void progressUpdater_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // update the UI with appropriate fields
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            labelCommunicating.Text = "In progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage + "% complete";
        }

        void progressUpdater_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        void progressUpdater_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            while (true)
            {
                if (progressPercentage >= 100)
                {
                    break;
                }

                worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateProgress(int progressPercentage)
        {
            this.progressPercentage = progressPercentage;
        }

        private void ProgressIndicator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker progressUpdater = new BackgroundWorker();
            progressUpdater.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            progressUpdater.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            progressUpdater.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(progressUpdater_DoWork);
            progressUpdater.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(progressUpdater_RunWorkerCompleted);
            progressUpdater.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(progressUpdater_ProgressChanged);

            progressUpdater.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't any way that the code you posted could repro the problem.  You are using Sleep() in DoWork, that will always hide the issue.  But *real* DoWork event handlers often call ReportProgress too often.  Faster then the UI thread can keep up, it will start to lag behind.  Call if often enough and it doesn't get around to do its low priority duties.  Like responding to user input or painting the controls.  It will look dead.  Humans only can see progress at a rate of 25 times per second, *way* less than what it takes to flood the UI thread.

Comment: Huh?  You don't update progress at all when doing the "work" (DoWork handler).  Plus, you don't show an example of how UpdateProgress is even called.  Normally "progress" is an indication of work done; which is something done by the DoWork handler.

Comment: Hans: sleep is added so that the application doesn't hog resources. Peter: the work is done elsewhere, what the `DoWork` method does here is check the progress and update the screen accordingly. The progress is changed in the `UpdateProgress` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a far-fetched solution and I think your problem lies with the `while loop`. However, a better approach may be to simply update your `ProgressBar` without blocking the UI by using `Invoke();` e.g.

```
Invoke(new myUpdate(updateProgress), pval);//call invoke whenever you need to update the progress bar assuming pval is an integer with the value to update with. This could be in a thread for instance.

//declare this as a class level delegate
private delegate void myUpdate(int progress);

//method to update progress bar
private void updateProgress(int progress)
{
    progressBar.Value = progress;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This seems much better than what I'm trying to do.

I'm getting an error on that first line where it says `updateProgress`. It says that `updateProgress` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: There was a little error but it's updated now. Make sure all the methods and delegates and calls are inside the form class where you are updating the progress.

Comment: I am doing the call from another class. How can I make the code correct to do this?

Comment: If you need to use a class, you can declare it as an object and use it in the main class. e.g. `MyWorker work = new MyWoker();` `Invoke(new myUpdate(updateProgress), work.Progress);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the process in this fashion that way you do not need to wrap your call around the Invoke method.

```
//delegate method
private delegate void updateProgressDelegate(int progress);

//actual method
private void updateProgress(int progress)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new updateProgressDelegate(updateProgress), progress);
    }
    else
    {
        progressBar.value = progress;
    }
}
```